# Custom view classes in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

So I am building a Swing layout in IntelliJ IDEA using the layout manager GridLayoutManager(IntelliJ).

It's going ok, I can layout all my stuff etc but everything is in the same code file and considering I am using a JPanel with a JTabbedPane, I would like each pane of the tabbed pane to be represented in a separate class.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could do this, either extending `JPanel` or creating another class which contains a `JPanel`

*Inheritance Based Solution*

```
public class MyCustomPanel extends JPanel {

    // implement your custom behavior in here
}
```

Then in your where you create your `JTabbedPane` you'd have something like this:

```
private void init() {
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel jp = new MyCustomPanel();
    jtp.add(jp);
}
```

Although this works, extending `JPanel` may cause headaches in the long run.  Another approache, which favors [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) might look something like this:

*Composition Based Solution*

```
public class MyCustomPanel {
    private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

    public MyCustomPanel() {
        // add your customizations to myPanel
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return myPanel;
    }
}
```

and then where you create your `JTabbedPane`

```
private void init() {
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    MyCustomPanel mp = new MyCustomPanel();
    jtp.add(mp.getPanel());
}
```